# Why is sigset_t in glibc/musl 128 bytes large on 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, c, signals, glibc

Why is `sigset_t` on 64-bit Linux 128 bytes large in glibc and musl?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(sigset_t)); //prints 128 with both glibc and musl
}
```

Shouldn't 64 / 8 = 8 (`number_of_signals / CHAR_BIT`) be enough?

Comment: @thrig http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/ia64/include/asm/signal.h#L27 suggests the kernel's defining it as a 64 bit quantity (8 bytes), so I have no idea what the libc's are doing. I wish they at least commented that stuff.

Comment: my bad: glibc HAS commented it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don’t know the original reason; back in 1996, the Linux-specific header was [added](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigset.h;h=69648b7e9c487fc4eda565b6a97fe926ef5d8bfc;hb=df4ef2ab9c0899b267006) with the following definition:

```
/* A `sigset_t' has a bit for each signal.  Having 32 * 4 * 8 bits gives                                           
   us up to 1024 signals.  */                                                                                      
#define _SIGSET_NWORDS 32                                                                                          
typedef struct                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                  
  unsigned int __val[_SIGSET_NWORDS];                                                                              
} __sigset_t;
```

and this “1024 signal” limit has been preserved in the current definition:

```
/* A `sigset_t' has a bit for each signal.  */                                                                     

#define _SIGSET_NWORDS (1024 / (8 * sizeof (unsigned long int)))                                                   
typedef struct                                                                                                     
  {                                                                                                                
    unsigned long int __val[_SIGSET_NWORDS];                                                                       
  } __sigset_t;
```

which makes the 1024-based calculation clearer (and results in 16 unsigned longs on 64-bit x86, *i.e.* 128 bytes).

Presumably the glibc maintainers wanted to leave room for growth...

musl aims for ABI compatibility with glibc for `sigaction`, so it uses [the same 1024-bit (128-byte) size](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/include/alltypes.h.in#n66):

```
TYPEDEF struct __sigset_t { unsigned long __bits[128/sizeof(long)]; } sigset_t;
```