# Is sigprocmask() not working correctly?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, c, signals, glibc

*(Sorry for the long post but I wanted to be as accurate as possible)*

I was trying to print the signal mask of the main thread while writing a C program, when I came across something strange regarding how the `sigprocmask` function works.

**Background** [Source: manual page `sigprocmask(2)`] 
The `sigprocmask` function is used to fetch and/or change the signal mask of the calling thread.

```
/* Prototype for the glibc wrapper function */
int sigprocmask(int how, const sigset_t *set, sigset_t *oldset);
```

- If `oldset` is non-`NULL`, the previous value of the signal mask is stored in `oldset`.
- If `set` is `NULL`, then the signal mask is unchanged (i.e., `how` is ignored), but the current value of the signal mask is nevertheless returned in `oldset` (if it is not `NULL`).
- A set of functions for modifying and inspecting variables of type `sigset_t` ("signal sets") is  described  in `sigsetops(3)`. In example:

  - `int sigemptyset(sigset_t *set);`: initializes the signal set given by set to **empty**, with all signals excluded from the set.
  - `int sigfillset(sigset_t *set);`: initializes set to **full**, including all signals.
  - `int sigismember(const sigset_t *set, int signum);`: tests whether signum is a member of set.

*Note*: When creating a filled signal set, the glibc `sigfillset` function does not include the **two** real-time  signals used internally by the NPTL threading implementation.

**System specifics** 
Linux Distribution: Linux Mint `19.3` Cinnamon 
Glibc version: `2.27` (default) 
Also verified for Glibc version: `2.31.9`

Output of `uname -a`: 
`Linux 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Problem Replication**

The program that alarmed me of something possibly going wrong is the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32

#define OUTOFBOUNDS
#undef  OUTOFBOUNDS

void print_set_bin(sigset_t *setp);

int main(void)
{
    sigset_t set;

    printf("NSIG = %d\n\n", NSIG);

    printf("Empty set:\n");
    if (sigemptyset(&set))  
    {
        perror("sigemptyset");
        return -1;
    }
    print_set_bin(&set);

    printf("Filled set:\n");
    if (sigfillset(&set))   
    {
        perror("sigfillset");
        return -1;
    }
    print_set_bin(&set);

    printf("After sigprocmask():\n");
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, &set))
    {
        perror("sigprocmask");
        return -1;
    }
    print_set_bin(&set); // Why non-empty?

    return 0;
}


void print_set_bin(sigset_t *setp)
{
    int sig, res;
    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (!setp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "print_set_bin(): NULL parameter\n");
        return;
    }

#ifdef OUTOFBOUNDS
    for (sig = 0; sig <= NSIG; sig++)
#else
    for (sig = 1; sig < NSIG; sig++)
#endif
    {
        res = sigismember(setp, sig);
        if (res == -1)
        {
            snprintf(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, "sigisimember [%d]", sig);
            perror(buff);
        }
        else
            printf("%d", res);
    }
    printf(" [%s]\n\n", sigisemptyset(setp) ? "Empty" : "Non-empty");
}
```

Function `print_set_bin` prints the output of `sigismember` (`0` for not a member, `1` for a member) for all signals. Macro definition `NSIG` (= 65) in `signal.h` is the biggest signal number plus one (1) as mentioned in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/signum-generic.h`. In the same file, it is also mentioned that this biggest signal number includes real-time signals (number range [32, 64]) and that signal number zero (0) is reserved for testing purposes.

As a result, my code posted above tests for signal numbers that belong in range [1, 64].

Below follows the **output** of the program:

```
NSIG = 65

Empty set:
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 [Empty]

Filled set:
1111111111111111111111111111111001111111111111111111111111111111 [Non-empty]

After sigprocmask():
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 [Non-empty]
```

**Output explantion** 
In this program, variable `set` of type `sigset_t` is manipulated. At first, function `sigemptyset` is used to set all bits to zero, then function `sigfillset` is used to set all bits to one (except from two; see *Note* in **Background** section) and finally `sigprocmask` is used to store current signal mask to the same variable. After all operations taking place on the signal set, function `print_set_bin` is used to print which signals belong to the set and whether the set is empty (using `sigisemptyset()`).

The problem seems to be the last call to `print_set_bin`, where no signal is found belonging to the set, but the `sigisemptyset` function characterizes the set as non-empty. That got me thinking whether `sigset_t` holds more than 64 bits and at least one of them is non-zero.

**Research** 
Tracing the header files included in `signal.h`, I found that `sigset_t` is a struct defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__sigset_t.h` as `__sigset_t.h` and `typedef`ed in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/sigset_t.h`:

```
#define _SIGSET_NWORDS (1024 / (8 * sizeof (unsigned long int)))
typedef struct
{
  unsigned long int __val[_SIGSET_NWORDS];
} __sigset_t;
```

At first I thought that 1024 bits were too many, but I then came across with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399342/why-is-sigset-t-in-glibc-musl-128-bytes-large-on-64-bit-linux/399356#399356) to another unix.stackexchange.com question.
I then decided to use the implementation details of the `sigset_t` struct to print all the 1024 bits. I did it in the code following, by replacing function `print_set_bin` with function `print_set_word` that prints all `_SIGSET_NWORDS` (= 16) `unsigned long int`s allocated to `__val` array.

```
void print_set_word(sigset_t *setp)
{
    int i;

    if (!setp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "print_set_word(): NULL parameter\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
            printf("%lu\n", setp->__val[i]);
    }
    printf("[%s]\n\n", sigisemptyset(setp) ? "Empty" : "Non-empty");
}
```

Program **output**:

```
Empty set:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
[Empty]

Filled set:
18446744067267100671
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
[Non-empty]

After sigprocmask():
0
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615
[Non-empty]
```

*Notes*:

- `18446744067267100671` == `0b1111111111111111111111111111111001111111111111111111111111111111` (64 bits set to 1 except from two; see *Note* in **Background** section)
- `18446744073709551615` == `0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` (64 bits set to 1)

**Output Explanation and Question** 
As you can see, `sigemptyset()` and `sigfillset()` manipulate all the 1024 bits of the set. Calling `sigemptyset()` instead of `sigfillset()` before calling `sigprocmask()` reveals that`sigprocmask()` manipulates only the first 64 bits (one `unsigned long int`), leaving the remaining 1024-64=960 bits untouched! And here comes the long-waited question: Isn't this a bug? Shouldn't `sigprocmask()` write to the whole struct data?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399342/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP If you read my question carefully, I refer the one you commented. The answer to that question verifies that `sizeof(sigset_t)` equals correctly to `128` Bytes.
My question is about the `sigprocmask` function that doesn't manipulate all the 128 bytes in `sigset_t`. It is a whole different thing.

Comment: It is, however, related, as I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `sigprocmask()` was not working correctly!

On 11-Mar-2020 I filled a new bug report on the glibc bug tracker.
A few minutes ago the bug status was changed to Resolved/Fixed as of glibc version `2.32`.

- Bug report: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25657
- Bug fix (commit): https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=566e10aa7292bacd74d229ca6f2cd9e8c8ba8748

Many thanks to the glibc developers involved in resolving this bug!